# Autohotkey Control + Capslock issue

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, capslock

I am using Autohotkey to make it so that you have to hit Shift + CapsLock in order to activate capslock. Then just pressing capslock gets you out of capslock. I love this script, however, when I switch tabs in chrome using Control + Tab, I sometimes end up hitting Contorl + Capslock, which activates capslock. Here is my code:

```
; Only allow capslock if it's shift-capslock
$SC03a::
GetKeyState,caps,CapsLock,T

if caps = D
    SetCapsLockState,Off
return
```

I don't know how to get around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only allow capslock if it's shift-capslock:

```
   CapsLock::SetCapslockState AlwaysOFF
   +CapsLock::SetCapslockState AlwaysON
```